# How to make the unique pair of values in array with php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display the unique pairs values in array.and to print the pair only if addition of that pair is even number.Language to be used is PHP.

Comment: Sorry, but it is completely unclear what you ask. What "unique pairs" are you talking about?

Comment: You should read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

As you aren't explain well in your question but I tried , **Maybe helpful.**

```
<?php
$range1 = range(1,2000);//change as per your requirement

$i = 5; //change as per your requirement

$UniqueEvenPairs = array();
while($i > 0){

    shuffle($range1);
    $addition = (($range1[0] + $range1[10]));
    if($addition % 2 == 0){
        $UniqueEvenPairs[$i] = array("val_1"=>$range1[0] , "val_2"=>$range1[10] , "addition" =>$addition);
        $i--;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";print_r($UniqueEvenPairs);

?>
```

***OutPut***

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [val_1] => 836
            [val_2] => 500
            [addition] => 1336
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [val_1] => 293
            [val_2] => 319
            [addition] => 612
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [val_1] => 1604
            [val_2] => 742
            [addition] => 2346
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [val_1] => 432
            [val_2] => 1606
            [addition] => 2038
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [val_1] => 896
            [val_2] => 1766
            [addition] => 2662
        )

)
```